# How do I collect the column headers that have non-empty cells for each row?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that lists who is working on what, with numbers to indicate how long they think it will take (the other cells are left blank).

```
       | Alex | Betty | Charlie |
---------------------------------
Task A |   1  |   2   |         |
Task B |      |       |    2    |
Task C |   1  |       |    3    |
```

I would like to generate a column called "Owners" that is a comma-separated list of who is working on each task, based on the non-empty values in the Alex, Betty, and Charlie columns. For example, Task A is being worked on by Alex and Betty, so the value in "Owners" for that row would be "Alex, Betty".

```
       | Alex | Betty | Charlie | Owners
------------------------------------------------
Task A |   1  |   2   |         | Alex, Betty
Task B |      |       |    2    | Charlie
Task C |   1  |       |    3    | Alex, Charlie
```

What's the best way to do this in Google Sheets? Note that my headers may not be in row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:D="",,B1:D1&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: This is slick but a bit confusing. What is it doing? The two transposes, a query with an empty query, and the 9^9 magic number are all a bit unclear

Comment: @emmby IF B2:D range is empty do nothing else bring down the headers from range B1:D1 and add comma to it. then smash it all into one column with TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( ... 9^9 - means "all rows". then TRIM the column to remove double spacing which was auto-added in the previous step by cells that do not hold any values. then  REGEXREPLACE the comma on the end to nothing